# LocalStorage Vs Application Storage(Storing data in service), which would have faster retrival time

Tags: angular, local-storage

I have been wondering about the retrieval times of both localStorage and the data stored in application like in form of a variable in a service, not sure how to know which is faster, if there was a way to measure or to know which one is fastest, it would be great, tried googling didn't help much.

Comment: It depends of the size of the data and tye of the data, if you have static data like for example user token each time you will need it you will invoke the service or just get it simple from the localStorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance of storage:

**Global variables:** The DOM and Javascript globals are both stored in RAM/ system memory. Globals are essentially just raw storage with very little structure, making them very fast.

**DOM values:** DOM values means walking the tree which can be slow.
The DOM is highly structured and whenever it changes it issues a range of events - these events (such as triggering style updates and mutation events/ mutation observers) add to the overhead.

**LocalStorage:** LocalStorage means reading/writing to disk.
localStorage however, is stored on the hard drive. It has all the overhead of writing out to the disk every time it's used, but it's persistent - if the browser is closed, or the device is turned off, the data you put in there will still be available. It's best used for e.g. caching files.

**AJAX:** AJAX requests means you have additional network latency.

**Most data in Javascript is completely temporary, so most of the time, you'd use globals.**

Comment: If my answer works for you, please accept the answer.